# Issue creating DbContext connection with LINQPad using Entity Framework 6.0 code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, datasource, dbcontext, linqpad

I'm using LINQPad v4.51.03 and attempting to create a DbContext connection from a code-first implementation in Entity Framework 6.0 (6.1.1).

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext    
{    
    public MyEntities() : base("mydbname") { ...
```

The connection string looks like:

`<add name="mydbname" connectionString="Data Source=<db>;initial catalog=<cat>;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

In the LINQPad 'Add connection' wizard everything seems to set up correctly when attempting to create a DbContext connection (using the parameter-less constructor) until I click test, at which point I receive the following error: "Error: Keyword not supported: 'data source'".

I'm guessing EF 6.0 no longer supports that type of connection string (even though it still works).  How would I create the LINQPad connection for code-first implementations?

Comment: You didn't tell, but from your description I understand you also enter a path to a correct config file. This should work with EF 6.

Comment: Ah, it should be `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Only wasted a couple of hours on it.