# Where should I place a custom DbContext in ASP.NET MVC app for LINQPad to reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, linqpad

I am trying to establish a connection between LINQPad and my solution's DbContext generated with EF 6.0, but when I select the assembly reference, I get this error: `There are no types based on System.Data.Linq.DataContext in that assembly`. I am assuming this means that I need to create a custom DbContext class that LINQPad can reference in my solution assembly. Where in my ASP.NET MVC application's file tree structure should I create a custom DbContext class that LINQPad can reference? This is my first time using LINQPad and working with ASP.NET MVC; maybe I am not connecting the dots between previous SO solutions offered on [troubleshooting LINQPad connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627215/issue-creating-dbcontext-connection-with-linqpad-using-entity-framework-6-0-code), [creation of classes inheriting from DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852687/is-there-a-linqpad-equivalent-to-a-datacontext-class), or [LINQPad's help guides](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx)?

Comment: which vs are you using 2013 or 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new connection in LinqPad and you choose "Entity Framework (DbContext)" in the lower part of the first window, then in the next window you point to your project.dll in bin/debug (release) directory, normally LinqPad will find the DbContext entity and you have to choose your web.config.
You have nothing more to do in you MVCproject.

Comment: thanks for the post. It is precisely after following the steps you have described that the error message referenced in my question is produced.

Comment: This is my first time using LINQPad.

Comment: I relaunched VS and updated my database again, and now LINQPad is auto-magically locating my DbContext. It is unfortunate that I cannot pinpont exactly what was producing the error (literally nothing else in my application has changed). But at least now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-built your project before linking it in Linqpad ?